# How can I filter by start date in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, date, filter

I have a search feature that should allow a user to sort through a list of courses based on a few factors such as the course language, subject, effort, and whether the course is open for enrollment, opening for enrollment soon, or archived; based on the date property in the course object. I have the other functions working well but the date sort is stumping me.

I'm blaming lack of sleep last night for my inability to wrap my head around this seemingly simple problem.

My addled brain believes that the proper way to begin this is to parse the date and create a filter along the lines of this ...

```
namespace.filter('dateFilter', function(){
    //following is psuedocode
    var output[];
    if(dateNow > ds.course_open_date) {logic}
    if(dateNow > ds.course_open_date + 30 days) {logic}
    if(dateNow > ds.course_close_date) {logic}
    if(boolean ds.course_self_paced = true) {logic}
    return output;
});
```

I could use a push in the right direction. I need sleep.

Comment: did u try | orderBy:'-date' filter on ng-repeat  ??

Comment: @MohsinMuzawar yes, and while that would sort my entire list by date, unfortunately it doesn't accomplish what I'm after which is to manipulate the DOM so as to limit what is visible to courses that pass through the filter.

Comment: can you show me what your COURSE object array looks like ??